# How to handle chat room in terms of performace and scalabity using mysql and php

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, database-design

I have been searching all day to find a better answer to my question but those I found was useful
but do not critically analyse my question.

I am building a chat room using php, mysql, jquery and ajax. 
The target group members are 3000 people who will frequently 
chat every day, so I am expecting like one million messages a day. 
The chat room is open to all the members, that means 
every member has the same priviledge to send and view 
sent messages.

In this case, every member has the permission to delete messages whether sent by him or different members,
however deleted messages should not affect other users. I wouldnt also keep messages for more than two days,
meaning every sent message should be deleted after two days.

Below are the sample tables that represents the logics above

```
users table

|  u_id | 
|  name |  


messages table

| msgID            |  
| msgBODY          |
| msgTime          |
| senderID--FK     |
| deleted_by_sender|


recipient table

| recID               |
| msgID--FK           |
| recipientID ---FK   |
| deleted_by_recipient|
```

Now, if I am to implement the schema above, it means that every single sent message has to do 3000 inserts into the 
recipient table and one insert into the messages table. This also means that if there are 50 sent messages within 1 minute there would be more
inserts within the one minute. At the same time 3000 people are viewing the messages. Awwsh! more work load on the database within that minute.
hmm!

Please is there a way to handle this, scalability and performance wise?

Any idea is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: DELETE has a specific meaning in MySQL. When you say 'delete', you really mean 'hide from [my] view'?

Comment: Yes please @ Strawberry

Comment: I mean, when a user deletes a specific message, that particular message should be hidden from him or her

Comment: Please clarify. 1. Is every message viewable by every member? 2. If so, what is the recipients table for? 3. Finally, it seems that you just need a table of 'marked_hidden' messages that just stores the id of the message, and the id of the user who no longer wishes to view it.

Comment: Yes,every message is viewable by every member, as you can see from the recipients table, there is a column labeled `deleted_by_recipient`, this will contain either yes or no values. It is there to hide a particular message to a particular user who has the yes value (user who no longer wishes to view it.). I hope this makes it clearer